# My php page generate a json without table name

Tags: php, json

im trying to generate a simple json object from a php page listed here:

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("******","*******","") or die("Errore connessione al sito");
    mysql_select_db("*******") or die("Errore selezione database");
    $q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM personaggio");
    while($e=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
        $output[]=$e;
    print(json_encode($output));
    mysql_close();
?>
```

i expect something like this :

```
{ 
        "personaggio" : 
            [{  
                "Nome":"Rafael",
                "Password":"chimeratech",
                "Gold":"1100",
                "Food":"2",
                "Pf":"96",
                "Date":"0875-06-18",
                "Exp":"178000"
              },
              {
                "Nome":"Vandermax",
                "Password":"leechaolan",
                "Gold":"200",
                "Food":"3",
                "Pf":"145",
                "Date":"0875-06-18",
                "Exp":"126000"
               }
            ]
    }``
```

but what i get is :

```
   [
        {  
            "Nome":"Rafael",
            "Password":"chimeratech",
            "Gold":"1100",
            "Food":"2",
            "Pf":"96",
            "Date":"0875-06-18",
            "Exp":"178000"},
            {"Nome":"Vandermax",
            "Password":"leechaolan",
            "Gold":"200",
            "Food":"3",
            "Pf":"145",
            "Date":"0875-06-18",
            "Exp":"126000"
        }
    ]``
```

so my table name "personaggio" is missing ... how can i correctly get the expected json file?

Comment: So where is the line of code that you use to try and store the table name in $output? Perhaps you meant to use `print(json_encode(['personaggio' => $output]));
`

Comment: try this: `$output['personaggio'][]=$e;`

Comment: Could you post the array structure? print_r($output);

Comment: im sorry im new in json and php. 
i thought there was a standard way to get a json object. the fact is that i cant use it in an android application with the method getJSONArray cause he cant get the class name.

Answer (score 0):

From the `SELECT` query you won't get table name, If you want table name also in your result you need to save the table name in variable and assign the results in to table name variable

For eg:-

```
    mysql_connect("******","*******","") or die("Errore connessione al sito");
    mysql_select_db("*******") or die("Errore selezione database");
    $table_name = "personaggio"; // assign the table_name to variable
    $output = array(); // assign empty array for output variable
    $q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ". $table_name);
    while($e=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
        $output[$table_name][]=$e; // now collect the result array in table_name array

    print(json_encode($output)); // your expected output
    mysql_close();
```

You will get your expected output which the results array saved in **table_name**